# How can I allow all players to use the teleport command without the use of mods or op permissions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have just created a Minecraft 1.13.1 server and was wondering if there was any way to give everyone the teleport command even if they are not op. If not, is there a way that I could make them op but only have access to the teleport command?

Comment: These questions are clearly asking the same thing. The fact that one of them has only a mod-using answer means that it has an incomplete set of answers, not that this is not a duplicate.