# Is there any way to add a "wildcard" text to an execute command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As those who have seen/answered my questions before are aware, I run a modified SMP server for my Discord. I want to add a system where players can set their home, in a way, through a warp system, allowing them (and only them, which I can configure later) to warp there later. I've already got a warp to spawn through `/trigger`, but I was wondering if there was any possibility to add some form of wildcard to a command searching for a specific block or entity placement.

An example of what I want to do (not that this is possible, or if it is, I don't know how to do it); perhaps a system where, upon doing something like `/trigger setHome add 1`, the players are given a spawn egg named like, "@p's Home" or something. Then, a command block somewhere finds the entity and who summoned it, created a trigger warp for that person, and enables it, thus allowing the player to use `/trigger <home> add 1` to teleport to wherever they placed the entity.

As far as I'm aware, having such a wildcard text is impossible since most Minecraft commands run on specifics, especially when dealing with scoreboards and the sort.

I should point out that this is running on 1.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is no way to get a player's name into an item name or similar.

Something like this was suggested many times, one of the more popular suggestion was a "`/compose`" command, but it was rejected by a developer due to security issues, for example if something had a closing bracket or quotation mark in their name, it could mess up the rest of the command. Of course this could be solved relatively easily with automatic escaping, but I haven't followed the development of the suggestion any further, so I don't know if anyway has e.g. contributed code like that yet. It's certainly possible to implement that or something similar into Minecraft, but it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: That's a shame! I would actually really love to see something like that. Do you know of any way I can do this home warp system them?

Comment: Using triggers? I thought you had already done that.

Comment: I've got one in place for warping to spawn, but not for users to create their own warps that only they can use, like using ``/trigger`` to warp only them to their particular house.

Comment: You can only make commands react to certain scoreboard values that are set with trigger, so you basically just copy the tp-to-spawn system multiple times. But you could for example make a system of checkpoints, similar to this: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338998/allow-everyone-to-have-access-to-teleport-command-on-minecraft-server/339010#339010 You could also restrict it to a player's current coordinates by **getting** their location in the same way as I **set** the location of the armour stand in that answer over there.